# OEM 13C Log File Monitoring

Tags: oracle

I have installed OEM 13c and deployed a couple of agents and want to test out the Log File Monitoring utility.  I have enabled it and added a log file to monitor.

[image]

When I go and test it out, it does not show any alerts when they are put into the Log File.  On the agent server, I have tailed the file and see the messages coming into the log file.

[image]

Does anyone have experience adding log files to OEM?  I could have configured it wrong.  Or is there any troubleshooting steps that I can follow to see if the server is even contacting the agent for reading the log file.  Status of the agent is good with no incidents.

Answer (score 1):

Without access to the system, it would be difficult to tell you the exact cause of this issue.  However, I can list a few potential causes of this issue that I have experienced personally:

- Permissions.  The Oracle Enterprise Manager Agent is very convoluted when it comes to system permissions within a remote server.  The agent can be owned and run as any number of users but during metric evaluation, may also need sudo or pam-authentication permissions to access certain entities on the server.  Depending on the authentication profiles on that server, this could be the cause of your issue.  There are ways to grant the agent access through the PAM stack if that is necessary.
- Syntax.  The wildcard syntax in the OEM GUI can be a little confusing as well.  I would play with the wildcard elements a bit on the "String" component to ensure that it isn't as simple as adding wildcards to the beginning and end of the string.  Without diving into the binaries of the agent plugins, it is difficult to assess exactly how the agent is evaluating this particular metric

One suggestion I would have is to go through the agent commands.  There are specific commands you can run to manually force an agent to evaluate a particular metric for a particular target.  This can allow you to manually trigger the metric collection locally on the server and evaluate what exactly is being performed at the agent level.

On the system I was running (12c) the command was as follows:

```
emctl control agent runCollection <hostname>:host host_storage
```